# 1-propanamine to cyclopropane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

I was solving some questions on amines when I happened to see the below question:

> propan-1-amine + ($\ce{NaNO2 + HCl}$)= a mixture of products 
>   (originally, the mixture in brackets on the reactant side was just
>   written as $\ce{HNO2}$)
>
> The mixture contains:
>
> a.    1-Propanol
>
> b.    2-Propanol
>
> c.    Cyclopropane
>
> d.    All of these

The answer happened to be "d. All of these". I could understand the formation of 1-propanol and 2-propanol but not cyclopropane. The answer given in the textbook wasn't clear and I couldn't understand. It said that the carbocation intermediate had something to do with it which I couldn't follow.

Can someone explain what is behind all this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Diazotisation of primary amines gives the diazonium salt which decomposes to the primary cation and $\ce{N2}$. From this, in aq. $\ce{HCl}$, you directly get the primary alcohol, primary chloride and primary nitro by immediate trapping of the primary cation by ions in solution and the terminal alkene by 1,2 elimination.
- A cation shift to give the secondary cation also occurs to give secondary alcohol and secondary chloride.
- The cyclopropane arises from a 1,3-elimination of the primary cation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

pics from reference 1

**References**

1. [Amines with Nitrous Acid - chem.libretexts.org](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Basic_Principles_of_Organic_Chemistry_(Roberts_and_Caserio)/23%3A_Organonitrogen_Compounds_I-_Amines/23.10%3A_Amines_with_Nitrous_Acid)
2. *Nitrosation, diazotisation, and deamination* by J. H. Ridd  Q. Rev. Chem. Soc., **1961**, 15, 418-441 DOI: https://doi.org/10.1039/QR9611500418

Comment: Reaction equations added